# Setting Shell Positional Parameters With "set ls -AF"

Tags: shell, set, ksh, ifs

I am writing a *ksh* function (that is placed in the *.profile* file) that will present a menu of subdirectories and permit the user to choose one into which to *cd*.  Here is the code:

```
# Menu driven subdirectory descent.
d(){
# Only one command line argument accepted
[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift $# #   Trap for "ls --" feature
wd=`pwd`; arg="${1:-$wd}"
dirs="`/bin/ls -AF $arg  2>/dev/null | grep /$ | tr -d \"/\"`"
#       Set the names of the subdirectories to positional parameters
if [ "$dirs" ] ;then
        set $dirs
        if [ $# -eq 1 -a "$arg" = "$wd" ] ;then cd $arg/$1; return; fi # trap: it's obvious; do it
else echo "No subdirectories found" >&2; return 1
fi
#       Format and display the menu
if [ `basename "${arg}X"` = "${arg}X" ] ;then arg="$wd/$arg"; fi # Force absolute path if relitive
echo -e "\n\t\tSubdirectories relative to ${arg}: \n"
j=1; for i; do echo -e "$j\t$i"; j=`expr $j + 1`; done | pr -r -t -4 -e3 
echo -e "\n\t\tEnter the number of your choice -- \c "
#       Convert user-input to directory-name and cd to it
read choice; echo
dir=`eval "(echo $\{"$choice"\})"`  #       Magic here.
[ "$choice" -a "$choice" -ge 1 -a "$choice" -le "$#" ] && cd $arg/`eval echo "$dir"`
}
```

This function works reasonably well with the exception of directory names that contain *space* characters.  If the directory name contains a *space*, the *set* command sets each space delimited element of the directory name (instead of the complete directory name) into a separate positional parameter; that is not useful here.

I have attempted to set the *$IFS* shell variable (which contains a *space*, *tab*, and *newline* by default) to a single *newline* character with:

```
IFS=`echo`        # echo outputs a trailing newline character by default
```

Which appears to accomplish what is intended as verified with:

```
echo -e "$IFS\c" | hexdump -c
```

But despite my best efforts (over the course of several days work) I have failed to set the entire directory names that contain spaces as values for positional parameters.

What am I missing?

Suggestions are hereby solicited and most welcome.

ADVAthanksNCE

Bob

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84462/discussion-on-question-by-bob-bascom-setting-shell-positional-parameters-with-s).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't do that. Don't try. See [the ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) page for an understanding of why programmatic use of `ls` is inherently error-prone.

---

You can't get `-F` behavior without implementing it yourself in shell (which is indeed feasible), but the following is the *correct* way to put a list of subdirectories into the argument list:

```
set -- */
```

If you don't want to have a literal `/` on the end of each entry:

```
set -- */       # put list of subdirectories into "$@"
set -- "${@%/}" # strip trailing / off each
```

---

Even better, though: Use an array to avoid needing `eval` magic later.

```
dirs=( */ )
dirs=( "${dirs[@]%/}" )
printf '%s\n' "${dirs[$choice]}" # emit entry at position $choice
```

---

Let's tie this all together:

```
d() {
  destdir=$(
    FIGNORE= # ksh93 equivalent to bash shopt -s dotglob
    while :; do
      subdirs=( ~(N)*/ ) # ksh93 equivalent to subdirs=( */ ) with shopt -s nullglob
      (( ${#subdirs[@]} > 2 )) || break # . and .. are two entries

      for idx in "${!subdirs[@]}"; do
        printf '%d) %q\n' "$idx" "${subdirs[$idx]%/}" >&2
      done

      printf '\nSelect a subdirectory: ' >&2
      read -r choice
      if [[ $choice ]]; then
        cd -- "${subdirs[$choice]}" || break
      else
        break
      fi
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$PWD"
  )
  [[ $destdir ]] && cd -- "$destdir"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this technique.  It works brilliantly!

Comment: With regard to parsing ls, here is what appears to be a rebuttal to the pointer you kindly provided: <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls>.  Before accepting that this question has been answered, I'll post a working version that incorporates your kind suggestions.  Right now, here is a copy of a new version of the *d* function that passes *shellcheck*:

Comment: [Unfortunately I'm unable to post that code due to the limitation on character count stackexchange imposes on comments.]

Comment: You might consider posting your own answer with the code in question.

Comment: Being that this is my first experience with stackexchange, I'm not sure how to do that.  Ah, I see the box at the bottom of this page...

Comment: By the way -- another major bug with the proposed practices from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls%3E -- `?` is not the only glob character; attempting to expand a glob to replace `?`s with literally correct characters will also attempt to apply other glob expressions in the name -- square braces and the like.

Comment: @BobBascom, see complete solution amended to this answer.

Comment: (also, did you see how much code the person writing the question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls%3E had to use to get something that was semi-reliable? Would you want to need to do that every time you had a directory listing to perform?)

Answer (score 0):

Although still not working, this version does pass *shellcheck* albeit with one exception:

```
3  # Menu driven subdirectory descent.
4  function d{
5  # Only one command line argument accepted
6  [ "$1" = "--" ] && shift $#        # Trap for "ls --" feature
7  wd="$PWD"; arg="${1:-$wd}"
8  set -- "${@%/}"              #       Set the names of the subdirectories to positional parameters
9  if [ $# -eq 1 -a "$arg" = "$wd" ] ;then cd "$arg/$1" || exit 1; return; # trap: it's obvious; do it
10  else echo "No subdirectories found" >&2; return 1
11  fi
12  #       Format and display the menu
13  if [[ $(basename "${arg}X") = "${arg}X" ]] ;then arg="$wd/${arg}"; fi # Force absolute path if relitive
14  echo -e "\n\t\tSubdirectories relative to ${arg}: \n"
15  j=1; for i; do echo -e "$j\t$i"; j=(expr $j + 1); done | pr -r -t -4 -e3 
16  echo -e "\n\t\tEnter the number of your choice -- \c "
17  #       Convert user-input to directory-name and cd to it
18  read -r choice; echo
19  dir=(eval "(echo $\{\"$choice\"\})")        #       Magic here.
20  [ "$choice" -a "$choice" -ge 1 -a "$choice" -le "$#" ] && cd "${arg}"/"$(eval echo "${dir}")" || exit 1
                                                                                      ^SC2128 Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.
21  }
```

Once I have incorporated your suggestions into the code, and made it functional, I'll post it here, and mark my question answered.  Thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: `function` is bad form, being not present in POSIX sh -- use `d() {` instead.

Comment: There are also a great many comments I gave directly on the question (now moved to chat) which haven't been taken into account in this code.

Comment: (I misunderstood earlier, by the way -- thought you actually had a working answer you wanted to post -- when suggesting the "add an answer" button).

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your example code answer.  It seems to work as expected with a few exceptions.  1. It places a  backslash before space characters in directory names.  2.  The directory menu is displayed vertically.  While this will accommodate long directory names (which is useful), it limits the number of directory names the menu of choices may contain without scrolling off screen.  Your code is succinct and elegant, and I appreciate your sagacious assistance very much.  incidentally, *shellcheck* finds on line  6: "Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.

Comment: Oh, it also fails to display directory names that begin with a dot.

Comment: Yes -- expanding to the first element only was the intended behavior there; the alternative would be to enable the `nullglob` shell option to make empty globs expand to nothing at all, rather than expanding to a single array element containing only the glob expression itself. However, doing that would have side effects unless we were careful to turn it off on function exit.

Comment: With respect to directory names starting with a dot, that's what the `dotglob` option is for; looks like we might need to enable some non-default shell functions after all.

Comment: Moved the code in my answer into a subshell to allow state changes to be performed (such as enabling shell functions) without polluting other code.

Comment: When attempting to source your *d* function under *ksh* I receive this error: "ksh: .: syntax error: `(' unexpected".  I am grateful for your help none the less.  It is a superior starting place to begin further development of this function than my old code.  Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. `shopt` is indeed a bashism, but that's the only error I can reproduce.

Comment: Looked up the relevant ksh equivalents. Function given in my answer now works for me when tested with ksh93.

Comment: No more errors.  The only nit, is the single-quotes around directory names displayed in the menu that contain a space character.

Comment: That's a behavior of the `%q`, which emits strings in such a way that if you paste them into a shell, the shell will interpret them unambiguously. If you don't want such unambiguous interpretation (and want to run the risk of filenames with garbage in them corrupting your terminal configuration when printed), change the `%q` to `%s`.

Comment: 0) .root # d
    0) .
    1) ..
    2) admin
    3) .aptitude
    4) bin
    5) .cache
    6) .config
    7) .dbus
    8) Desktop
    9) .dillo
    10) Downloads
    11) .fltk
    12) .foo
    13) 'foo moo'
    14) .gconf
    15) .gnome2
    16) .gstreamer-0.10
    17) .gvfs
    18) .history
    19) indiecity
    20) .local
    21) Mail
    22) .Mathematica
    23) .netsurf
    24) Product
    [list truncated to accommodate limited comment length]
    Select a subdirectory: 13
    0) .
    1) ..
    
    Select a subdirectory: 12
    ksh[15]: cd: bad directory
    /root/foo moo #

Comment: Waitaminute. You're putting in `12` at a menu where the options are `0` and `1`? That should be no surprise when it fails. Just press enter to exit in the directory you're in at the time.

Comment: Eh. Edited to exit when only two entries exist.

Comment: I've got to run now.  But I'll be back to continue as time permits.  Many thanks for sharing your expertise with me.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code you kindly wrote as a basis for the *d* function below.  It pretty much does what I'd like, with a few little issues:

1. All subdirectory names that contain a SPACE character are surrounded by  characters, but those that do not are not.
2. All subdirectory names that contain a SINGLE QUOTE character have that character escaped with a BACKSLASH character.

Given that *1* and *2* above cause no issues, they are acceptable, but not ideal.

3. After user input does the *cd*, the menu of subdirectory names is again looped through.  This could be considered a feature, I suppose.  I tried substituting a *return* for the *brake* commands in the sections of code following the *cd* commands, but was unsuccessful in overcoming the subsequent looped menu.
4. The inclusion of "." and ".." at the head of the menu of subdirectories is not ideal, and actually serves no good purpose.

------------------- Code Begins ------------------------------

```
d() {
    if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
       echo "$FUNCNAME: ksh only";return 1
    fi

    FIGNORE= # ksh93 equivalent to bash shopt -s dotglob


    if [ ${#} -gt 0 ] ;then             # Only one command line argument accepted
      cd -- "$1" && return 0
    fi

    if [ `ls -AF1|grep /|wc -l` -eq 1 ] ;then       # cd if only one subdirectory
      cd -- `ls -AF1|grep /` && return 0
    fi

  destdir=$(
    while :; do
      subdirs=( ~(N)*/ ) # ksh93 equivalent to subdirs=( */ ) with shopt -s nullglob
      (( ${#subdirs[@]} > 2 )) || break # . and .. are two entries

      echo -e "\n\t\tSubdirectories below ${PWD}: \n" >&2

      for idx in "${!subdirs[@]}"; do
        printf '%d) %q\n' "$idx" "${subdirs[$idx]%/}" >&2
      done

      printf '\nSelect a subdirectory: ' >&2
      read -r
      if [[ $REPLY ]]; then
        cd -- "${subdirs[$REPLY]}" || break     # Continue to loop through subdirectories after cding
      else
        break
      fi
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$PWD"
  )
```

--------------------------- Code Ends ------------------------------------

So, overall I'm very pleased, and consider myself very fortunate to have received the knowledgeable assistance of such an accomplished Unix wizard. I can't thank you enough.